# Google+ button for iOS

Tags: ios, google-plus

Do you know how is it possible to add a Google+ button to a native iOS application ? I found a lot of detail to make that with Javascript or HTML5 but not using Objective-C.

Google provides an example in Objective-C to use their API at the following address but I found nothing inside it to simply add a Google+ button to my iPad app.

Do you have any information about this issue?

Comment: This question is off-topic for this site, you'll have better chance on [so].

Answer (score 3):

Google+ API has Objective-C support: http://developers.google.com/+/downloads